# What Approach to call Web API using jQuery with MVC+WebAPI Project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need some suggestions regarding access data from web API in the MVC project via ajax, but I am confused about which approach I need to follow.

Note: All Data is coming from API
Like Insert/Update/Select/Delete all work is from API ( Means MVC project access data from API)

I have a simple MVC project with a single page with 3 fields only.

Field Details

1. Company Name
2. Country --> Dropdown
3. State  --> Dropdown

Here Country dropdown is filled from MVC controller via API Now we need to fill up State dropdown on country dropdown change event via ajax.

Now my question is which approach I need to choose below to call state API and Why ?

1. Direct call Get state API in ajax without hitting MVC Controller
2. Get State API in ajax via MVC Controller and controller hit Web API

Comment: If you use a web api, you need to use ajax to update the controls on the web page, as well as place drop-down lists in Partial View. and it just possible via MVC Controller or Web API controller